# Override a List<T> property

Tags: c#, list, overriding

I need to over override a property from a List class. My class for example is setup as follows:

```
    public class Customer
    {
        private int _ID;
        private string _CustomerName;
        private List<CustomerAddress> _CustomerAddressList;

        public int ID { get { return _ID; } set { _ID = value; } }
        public string CustomerName
        {
            get { return _CustomerName; }
            set { _CustomerName = value; }
        }
        public List<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddressList
        {
            get { return _CustomerAddressList; }
            set { _CustomerAddressList = value; }
        }
    }

    public class CustomerAddress
    {
        private string _Address1;
        private string _TelephoneNumber;

        public string Address1
        {
            get { return _Address1; }
            set { _Address1 = value; }
        }

        public virtual string TelephoneNumber
        {
            get { return _TelephoneNumber; }
            set { _TelephoneNumber = value; }
        }
    }
```

Now I have my `Business Layer` class which inherits the customer class.

I can override the properities of the customer class, but i can't work out how to override the properties of the `CustomerAddress` class in my `CustomerBL` class? I don't want to override the List setting but to override the individual properties on each item in the list.

Comment: Can you give an example of something you want to override, to make your question more clear?

Comment: Business Later, shouldn't it have a customer property, instead of enheriting from customer?

Comment: Well you can't change the type of a property you want to override, but you could use an Interface for your Address. But i'm not sure if i understand your question clearly enough.

Comment: Hey Mark, I'd like to override the TelephoneNumber property.

Comment: Pleas give an example of what you're trying to achieve. Why creating entities and inheriting them for your BL classes? The entities represent things. The BL classes should mainpulate this things. A BL class method should receive and return business entities. That's much more flexible, testable, and decoupled.

Comment: @Derrick. Please give an example of how you would override this property (something not working, but which shows what you want to achieve), and why you have to override it, instead of implementing it directly.

Comment: @JotaBe. The Customer Class is designed as a baseclass. So the business layer which inherits from it can then apply more specific rules than the base class. 

So i would then create another class
        public class Worker : Customer
        {
            public override CustomerAddress.TelephoneNumber {get; set; }
        }

Trying to override it like that doesn't work.

Comment: @Derrick: I recommend you to have separate entities (objects to work with) and BL classes to work with this entities. I.e. Person a base class for Worker and Customer. Address an independent class which is used inside Person. And PersonBl a class with method like CreateNew(), AddAddress(), RemoveAddrres(), etc. This could manipulate Persons. If you need a more specialized behaviour for Workers, then you can inherit WorkerBl from PersonBl, and replace or add special method for it. You can even hav a WorkerAddress, inherited from Address that you use in WorkerBl to implement AddAddress and so on

Comment: @Derrick CONT: This pattern makesmuch more flexible (and decoupled) the definiton of entities and functionality. Doing so you make it easier to correct the implementation of your business classes if you have to introduce changes in your entities. For example, you could have methods like `WorkerBl.AddAdress(Person worker, Address newAddress); List<Address> PersonBl.GetAdresses(Person person); PersonBl.ChangeAddress(Person person, Address changedAddress);` and so on.

Comment: @Derrick CONT: you can even have an AddresBl that can be used by PersonBl (or WorkerBl) for example to verify an address. I.e. `bool AddresBl.VerifyAddress(Address address)`. The implementations of `PersonBl.ChangeAddress` and `PersonBl.AddAddress` coul instance AddressBL and verify the address before adding of updating it. This would make your code cleaner.

Comment: @JotaBe: Thanks i can revisit the design as you recommended. But for future reference, how would i be able to override the list value? Or is impractical and I should revisit my class design?

Comment: with your current design, you can't do that. When you inherit a class you can override the members (properties, fields methods) of the class you are inheriting, not of the classes used or defined within the inherited class (Address in this case). I'll add an answer on how to do it.

Comment: @Jotbe: Awesome thanks, but I do think my issue is coming down to design in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the original design, there are only awful solutions:

```
    public class Customer
    {
        protected List<CustomerAddress> _customerAddresList 
           = new List<CustomerAddress>();
    }

    public class Worker : Customer
    {

    }

    public class CustomerAddress
    {
        protected string _Address1;
        public virtual string Address1
        {
            get { return "customer address: " + _Address1; }
            set { _Address1 = value; }
        }
    }

    public class WorkerAddress: CustomerAddress
    {
        public override string Address1
        {
            get { return "Worker Address: " + _Address1; }
        }
    }
```

If the entity instances are inherited, we have this:

```
    // Inheriting instances

    public class CustomerBL : Customer
    {
        public void AddAdress(CustomerAddress address)
        {
            _customerAddresList.Add(address);
        }
    }

    public class WorkerBL: Worker
    {
        // Not inehritable, different signature
        public void AddAdress(WorkerAddress address)
        {
            _customerAddresList.Add(address);
        }
    }
```

If we inherit the BL classes, we have this:

```
    // Inheriting BL
    public class CustomerBL2 : Customer
    {
        public virtual void AddAdress(CustomerAddress address)
        {
            _customerAddresList.Add(address);
        }
    }

    public class WorkerBL2 : CustomerBL2
    {
        public override void AddAdress(CustomerAddress address)
        {
            if (!(address is WorkerAddress))
                throw new Exception();
            base.AddAdress(address);
        }
    }
```

If we use Generics, we have this

```
    // Using generics
    public class Generic<TAddress>
    {
        private List<TAddress> _addresList
            = new List<TAddress>();
        protected virtual List<TAddress> AddresList
        {
            get { return _addresList; }
        }
    }

    public class CustomerG : Generic<CustomerAddress>
    {
    }

    public class WorkerG : Generic<WorkerAddress>
    {

    }
```

The problem, no doubt, is that there are two different inheritance chains:

- one of entities
- another of BL classes

And it's not possible to have a good decision on which is the rigth waty to do it (in fact, I think, with this design there's no way of doing it right).

It's much better to have entities and BL classes independent of each other, so that you can keep both inheritance chains independent, and decide what can and should be inherited in its chain.

```
    public class Address
    {
    }
```

Entities can inherit for each other. All right, typical case:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public List<Address> Adresses;
    }

    public class Worker: Person
    {
        // inherits adresses
    }
```

Inheriting BL Classes (dont' like it):

```
    public class PersonBl
    {
        // Functionality which is common fot all the inheritance chain
        public void PrintAdresses(Person person)
        {
        }

        // Functionality that can be specialized for each inherited entity
        public virtual void SaveAdresses(Person person)
        {
            // they're are treated differently in each case
        }

        // Functionality specific of person
        public void DoSomethingWithPerson(Person person)
        {
            // TODO
        }
    }

    public class WorkerBl : PersonBl
    {
        // Uses PersonBl PrintAdresses

        public override void SaveAdresses(Person person)
        {
            // do it for worker
        }

        // Functionality specific of Worker
        public void DoSomethingWithWorker(Worker worker)
        {
            // TODO
        }
    }
```

"BL classes using other BL classes" (that's the way I like it):

```
    public class Person2Bl
    {
        // Functionality which is common for all the inheritance chain of entities
        public void PrintAdresses(Person person)
        {
        }

        public void SaveAdresses(Person person)
        {
           // specific for person
        }

        // Functionality specific of person
        public void DoSomethingWithPerson(Person person)
        {
        }
    }


    // doesn't inherit:

    public class Worker2Bl
    {
        // Use the logic in PersonBl2
        public void PrintAdresses(Worker worker)
        {
            // Really not necessary -> this could be done directly in the app code
            Person2Bl bl = new Person2Bl();
            bl.PrintAdresses(worker);
        }

        public void SaveAdresses(Worker worker)
        {
           // specific of Worker
        }

        public void DoSomethingWithWorker(Worker worker)
        {
            // specific of worker
        }
    }
```

In fact, it would be better to have an AddressBl that can be used by both WorkerBl2 and PersonBl2

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not inherit your business entities from entities from some other layer. Use mapping instead (either manually or with some tool like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/)).

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's not very clear what you're trying to achivee, but considering your comment:

> So i would then create another class public class Worker : Customer {
>   public override CustomerAddress.TelephoneNumber {get; set; } } Trying
>   to override it like that doesn't work

I would do that like:

```
public class Customer 
{
    protected string telNumber =string.Empty; 
    public virtual string TelephoneNumber 
    {
      get { return telNumber ; }
      set {telNumber =value;}
    }
}

public class Worker : Customer 
{
   public override string TelephoneNumber 
   {
       get 
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Worker");
          return telNumber ; 
       }
       set {telNumber = value;}
   }
}
```

and after if you use it inside the code, like this:

```
Customer curst = new Worker(); 
var telNumber = curst.TelephoneNumber ;
```

it will make an output like this:

```
Worker
```

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: it's not entirely what i'm trying to achieive. I want to over right the inherited classes list classes property if that makes sense.

So Worker inherists the customer class as in your example. But Customer has a list of CustomerAddress, I want to overright the CustomerAddress Telephone number in my worker class.

Comment: @Derrick: it's not possible to do withous creating a derived class from CustomerAddress.

Comment: @Derrick: you derive from Customer so *can* override the properties/methods of Customer. If you need extend CustomerAddress, extend it with some CustomCustomerAddress and override property you need. After in the list of Worker clas, were needed add an instances of CustomCustomerAddress.